# PhoneGap Application from a MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cordova

I am beginner with PhoneGap. However I have successfully created a small PhoneGap application for ANDROID emulator. Now I want to start with something related to my project. I want to develop a web app using MVC4 for desktop/laptops and want to in turn develop a mobile application for Android/iOS using PhoneGap.But what I understood is that PhoneGap only take input pure HTML/JavaScript/CSS. My MVC4 application is having some csHTML files, some resource files etc. How can I convert these files to make them PhoneGap compliant.

I have googled a lot for this but not getting any meaningful.
Also please tell me that whether I am thinking in right direction or there is something beyond this.

One more point my MVC4 application is multilingual in nature based on the language of the browser. Does it make sense to have multilingual app on mobiles. If yes then how can I get the culture information on the mobile devices using PhoneGap.

If possible please share some live examples or code snippets.

Thanks.

Comment: Any news on this???? Whether I am thinking in right direction or not???? Please Help!!!!!!